# Check if os.system raise error during execution

Tags: python

My doubt is simple. I need to use a os.system on my code to call a extern function. This function can raise some error. How do i catch this?

Not just if it raise a command doesn't exist, but if the executed command (that i know that exists) raise any error during yor execution.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't. As [the docs for `os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) say, use the `subprocess` module if you want to retrieve the results of an external program.

Comment: Thanks, im checking https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html now